# Installing Zimbra Desktop mail client on Debian

Tags: debian

I tried installing [Zimbra Desktop Email](https://zimbra.org/download/zimbra-desktop) Client on Debian Sid
After installation, the client is not starting up and throwing the following errors.

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /zimbra/desktop/login.jsp. Reason:

    PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.lang.Class cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
java.util.Vector cannot be resolved to a type

Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.lang.Class cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
java.util.Vector cannot be resolved to a type


    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:123)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:296)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.loadTagFile(JspServletWrapper.java:261)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFile(TagFileProcessor.java:683)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.access$000(TagFileProcessor.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor$TagFileLoaderVisitor.visit(TagFileProcessor.java:739)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1501)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2291)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2341)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:498)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2291)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFiles(TagFileProcessor.java:757)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:222)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:435)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
    at com.zimbra.webClient.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:64)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.zimbra.cs.servlet.SetHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHeaderFilter.java:79)
    at com.zimbra.webClient.filters.SetHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHeaderFilter.java:239)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:422)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.rewrite.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:585)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:429)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:451)
Powered by Jetty://
```

Any pointers on resolving this would be helpful.

Comment: Did you follow the [documentation](https://zimbra.github.io/installguides/latest/single.html) properly?

Comment: Yes I did. This one here https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.zimbra.com/website/docs/7.3/Zimbra_Desktop_Install_Guide_7.3.0.pdf